# What are potions supposed to do In Find Mii 2?

Tags: streetpass-quest-find-mii-2

I recently completed Find Mii on my 3DS and unlocked Find Mii 2. When I started battling, I saw a new option that said "potion". I don't know what they are supposed to do. Are they used to heal a Mii or something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are different potions you can buy, and they each do different things, and cost a different number of Play Coins to buy and use.

The potions are:

- Vial of Valor - Calls back 3 heroes who have left the fight, costs 8 coins.
- Power Potion - Boosts your heroes' levels, costs 20 coins.
- Dispelling Draft - Gets rid of gas spewed by enemies (such as the curse gas which drops your fighters down by one level), costs 2 coins.
- Bottled Barrier - Protects you against enemy magic, costs 2 coins.

Some important things to remember: 
Sometimes you will buy a potion, and it will not do anything. Also, when you buy a potion, make sure you have a Mii behind the one purchasing the potion who will then use it. If you buy a potion and there are no more Miis waiting to fight, you will waste the potion.

Comment: Couple of notes — I've never had a Vial of Valor fail, and you can chain it forever as long as you have at least three Miis. The curse gas also gives a chance of actions failing entirely ("jinxed").